# Should I answer my own question? Was I wrong to post it?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, comments

Here's my question (oh boy, the meta effect is about to descend upon it):
[Suppress Google Chrome's "Your Connection is Not Private" for specific Address?](https://superuser.com/questions/960850/suppress-google-chromes-your-connection-is-not-private-for-specific-address)

Am I wrong to be asking the commenter for more details? He has probably given me enough details to work with that I can look it up myself and post the answer to my own question... but should I? It seems rude to post an answer to a question that someone gave you the starting point to in the comments. But this person seems insistent on not actually answering it (either in the comments or as a full answer).

Comment: If you know the answer to the question then you should answer it.  If I wanted the reputation for the answer I would have answered it.  I sometimes post hints to a possible solution when *I personally* feel more research should have been done, the question was good enough to merit the hint.

Comment: I don't think we have as strong a meta effect as Stack Overflow does :P

Comment: The general (meta-)question is addressed on Meta Super User at [What is the etiquette surrounding Asking and Answering Your Own Questions](http://meta.superuser.com/q/7184/150988), and on Meta Stack Exchange at [Can I answer my own questions, even if I knew the answer before asking?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/195817) (this is the main one), [When should I answer my own question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75305/195817), [When should/could I answer my own question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139153/195817),  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  [Should I answer my own question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132552/195817), and [Should I not answer my own questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12513/195817) (some of which are closed as duplicate of the others).  Reading between the lines, you seem to have qualms about potentially getting rep (exclusively) from an answer that was somewhat of a collaborative effort.  If you feel guilty about that, you can check the little “community wiki” checkbox at the bottom; that way, nobody will get rep from the answer.

Answer (score 11):

It's a matter of politeness more than 'is it right'. I'm encouraging ramhound to post an answer since he comments lots and answers less than he should ;p. However, it should be entirely fine, most of the time to post your own, detailed correct answer.

Comment: Have a look here.... http://superuser.com/questions/963520/delete-network-drive-on-windows-7. Is there something fishy with this? Where can i ask such questions?

Comment: Ask a new meta question, or flag it (with a custom flag! That answer makes sense to me so how its fishy is important) or ask it on the ask a SU moderator chatroom

Answer (score 2):

To further @Ramhound comments in your post, I've seen many users post comments instead of answers for a reason - some times on SU, it's not **always** about giving an answer, because it often doesn't help you to learn. When we are giving hints which you then need to research, you will find all the detail and more importantly, different approaches/opinions etc.

We could easily have answered a (any) question which works but, there is no guarantee that the answer we give is the most efficient/modern/simplist etc, despite it solving a problem. When you do your research, you'll obviously learn more about it and hopefully get a more balanced view.

So to answer you, leave a comment asking them to move to an answer. If they decline, then you know what to do, but maybe cite the comment in your answer.